# Find a script in subdirectories and execute the script along with the path

Tags: shell-script

I have a script called `service.sh` in many subdirectories under `/app/user`

```
/app/user/new1/service.sh
/app/user/new2/new3/service.sh
/app/user/new4/new5/new6/service.sh
```

My objective is to find all this `service.sh` and execute it which is unique along with subdirectory path and argument `stop,start` for each `service.sh` script.

for eg

```
/app/user/new1/service.sh stop
/app/user/new1/service.sh start
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say “unique”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `find` with `-execdir` combination:

```
find /app/user/ -type f -name 'service.sh' \
    -execdir ./service.sh stop   \; \
    -execdir ./service.sh start  \;
```

it will execute `./service.sh start` only if `./service.sh stop` was successful.

---

You can have a test with a script like below copied into both directory A& B:

the `script.sh` is:

```
# !/bin/sh

echo 'executing script in directory' "$PWD"
echo $1
echo
```

directory tree:

```
.
├── dir_A
│   └── script.sh
└── dir_B
    └── script.sh
```

running the command:

```
$ find -type f -name 'script.sh' -execdir ./script.sh stop \; -execdir ./script.sh start \;
executing script in directory /home/αғsнιη/test/dir_A
stop

executing script in directory /home/αғsнιη/test/dir_A
start

executing script in directory /home/αғsнιη/test/dir_B
stop

executing script in directory /home/αғsнιη/test/dir_B
start
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and Im going to test this today...Im happy to wakeup seeing the solution by my morning..You made my day!!

Comment: Hi,When I try to execute the script Im getting below error." find. the curren directory is included in the PATH env variable, which is insecure in combination with the -execdir action of find. please remove the current dir from your $PATH(that is, remove "." or leading or trailing colons)

Comment: Hi, please checkout [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/621132/283843) from me ;D and the answers explained there about that. also don't forgot to accept the answer if it resolved your question.

Comment: thanks a lot ..Its difficult for me to understand..Can you help me what should i rmeove from $PATH as i dont see /app/user over there.. Also im new to forum...How do i resolve and pass you stars?

Comment: Ok voted.. thx..i cant edit path variable as its secured server for the application I work..Do i have any other for loop option for the same requirement other than using execdir?